# Why we sum up the derivatives of the loss w.r.t. Weights at each time step in RNN back-propagation?

Tags: derivatives, neural-networks, error-propagation

I am reading a paper explaining the derivations of the back-propagation equations in RNNs.  There I read 'Note that the Weight Matrix remains the same across all time sequence so we can differentiate to it at each time step and sum all together.'

[image]

My question is why this statement is correct.  What is its mathematical derivation?

Your advice will be appreciated.

Comment: If your objective function is $|f(t_{end})-y|^2$ where $x$ is the input, $f_t(x)$ the output at time $t$, and $y$ the desired output then it means you don't care of the output at $t < t_{end}$, but you do care of the partial derivative $ \frac{\partial f(t_{end})}{\partial z_{j,t}}$ where $z_{j,t}$ is output of $j$-th neuron at time $t$. 
Also your RNN will be quite similar to a $t_{end}$-layer non-recurrent NN, and it is not really possible to train a NN with too many layers. The alternative is to choose objective function $\sum_t|f_t(x)-y_t|^2$ possibly with constant $y_t = y_0$.

Comment: The weights don't depend on $t$ so you'll have $\frac{\partial E}{\partial w_{i,j}} = \sum_t \sum_{t'\le t} \frac{\partial |f_t(x)-y_t|^2 }{\partial z_{j,t'}(x)}$

Comment: Thank you this helps.  Two questions:  1) In your second comment you meant to write w rather than z ? (the derivative is w.r.t. W).  2) What if we have a RNN modeling a many to one sequence (e.g., sentiment analysis task) where the error is calculated in the end only?